# Convert file From C:/fakepath/fileName ( path from form submit parameter ) to File object

Tags: java, file-upload, groovy

when I am trying to upload file from browser (form submit), In Java / Groovy I am getting

> C:/fakepath/fileName

but I am not able to convert that file into object due to wrong path.
 I am trying ..

```
new File(file_path_from_parameter); //for example
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. thanks

Comment: what `Exception` you get?

Comment: @SabirKhan >com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: File for key file must exist.

Comment: Does this `Exception` occur at line `new File(file_path_from_parameter);` , I don't think so if `fileName` file is present.If `C:/fakepath/fileName` is a valid path , `new File("C:/fakepath/fileName");` shouldn't fail.

Comment: @SabirKhan No, its not working if I hard code path                                  new File("/home/user/fileName"); i.e original file path from my linux machine. it works!